# Books on Sequential Workflow & State Workflow for Visual Studio 2008

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, visual-studio

Are there any good books that fulfill the below requirements:

[1] Provide at least 1 simple and 1 advance step-by-step on how to create a sequential workflow using Visual Studio 2008 (and also using SharePoint Designer 2007)?

[2] Provide at least 1 simple and 1 advance step-by-step on how to create a state machine workflow using Visual Studio 2008?

[3] Provide clear step-by-step on the deployment process for [1] and [2] on local SharePoint & remote SharePoint 2007 (and on a particular SharePoint List)

[4] Provide steps on how to involve 2 approvers in the work flow describe in [1] and [2] (It can be in sequence - one approve follow by another one ~or~ it can be concurrent - both will be known to approve)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not read any of these books, but check out these StackOverflow posts that cover the following books:

- [Professional SharePoint 2007 Workflow Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445128/how-do-i-get-started-developing-a-simple-workflow-application-in-sharepoint)
- [Pro WF Windows Workflow in .NET 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515179/how-to-get-windows-workflow-templates-in-visual-studio-2008)
- [Workflow in the 2007 Microsoft Office System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546/wss-moss-book)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I will go and read up those books. I am also open & welcome further book recommendation.